# Использование CSS стилей в JavaFX 8

Tags: java, gui, javafx

Не понимаю как добавлять более двух css-параметров в компонент.

Делаю так:

```
   this.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: silver; " +
            "-fx-font-size: 14px; "
    );
```

Дело в том, что при попытке добавления третьего, возникает ошибка парсера с сообщением о том, что превышен допустимый размер.

Проект [тут](https://github.com/Faoxis/Dipsach/blob/master/src/main/java/com/faoxis/dipsach/gui/topmenu/DipsachTopMenuBar.java).

Comment: делайте отдельным файлом .css и подключайте его для сцены

Comment: А как подключить отдельный css - файл и привязать его к классу (или объекту?) ?

Comment: scene.getStylesheets().add('path_to_css.css');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть простое решение для любого наследника Node.Вешайте стили сразу в StringProperty объект

Как пример:

```
Pane root = new Pane();
root.styleProperty().setValue(
      "-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-radius: 10px; -fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-radius: 10px; -fx-border-width: 10px;");
```